# How to resize WPF grid column with mouse and adorner

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a request from a WPF newbie to point me in the right direction for research prior to coding.

I want to do the following:

1. show a M row by N column grid on a canvas  (I have figured this one out)
2. When user left-clicks once in a column, I want to show an adorner around that column, indicating it is selected.
3. Now I want to allow user to resize the selected column by dragging mouse with left button down

My questions:

1. If I use GridSplitter, I can achieve #3 but will I also achieve #2 above?
2. Can Thumb control be useful for achieving either #2 or #3 or both?

Comment: Just wondering from a UX perspective, why you want to show the column as selected, when actually you are moving the boundary between two columns?